# How can I copy my data from NTFS Error Partition to external medium?

Tags: mount, ntfs

I think I made a beginner mistake when I installed Ubuntu 13.

I deleted my Windows 8 and then installed Ubuntu on my main partition as ext4. I also made a swap partition but I left my other 2 partitions (with important data on them) as NTFS because I was scared of losing data. When I try to open one of them I get following error:

```
"Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/markus/28167E1F167DEDE6: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/markus/28167E1F167DEDE6"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option."
```

I read something about Windows 8 hybrid shutdown that could solve my problem but I can't really change that, since I deleted my Windows.

Is there something else I can do or do I have to install Windows 8 again ?

Comment: " Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option." you need to do this to fix this. It is a windows problem that Ubuntu/mount can not fix for you. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

As Rinzwind mentioned, this isn't something Ubutnu can help you with.

The last time you used windows it was shutdown improperly.

You need to do one of the following

- Boot some of windows live cd (like winPE) so that you can run scandisk
- Remove the affected drive and attach it to a computer running windows and run scandisk
- Reinstall Windows and run scandisk on those partitions